# SQL/HQL DELETE statement for a LRU cache?

Tags: sql, caching, hql

I have a database being used to cache entities. The tables looks like this:

```
  | Persons                | Addresses
-----------------        -------------- 
PK| id           <--|    PK| id
  | last_accessed   |--- FK| persons_id
  | [some]                 | [more]
  | [other]                | [address]
  | [data]                 | [stuff]
```

So a person has zero or more addresses. These tables are accessed by a Java application using Hibernate and also directly from the same application using SQL over JDBC.

I now need to trim the size of the `Persons` table to a fixed value - say 50,000 records. I need to delete the oldest records (based on `last_accessed`) to do this.

**is there an ANSI-SQL or HQL query that could do this easily?** A pure ANSI-SQL solution would be ideal, since:

- we're trying to remain database agnostic;
- we want to avoid having to load objects into application memory to get Hibernate cascading deletes to work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pure ANSI SQL:

```
DELETE FROM addresses
WHERE persons_id IN ( 
   SELECT id 
   FROM ( 
      SELECT id, 
             row_number() over (order by last_accessed desc) as rn
      FROM persons
   ) t
   WHERE rn <= 50000
);

DELETE FROM persons
WHERE id IN ( 
   SELECT id 
   FROM ( 
      SELECT id, 
             row_number() over (order by last_accessed desc) as rn
      FROM persons
   ) t
   WHERE rn <= 50000
);
```

Another alternative would be to define the FK constraint with "ON DELETE CASCADE" and then just delete the rows from the `persons` table. That would get rid of the extra SQL for deleting the addresses first.